# maven surefirereport -doutputdirectory not working

Tags: java, maven, surefire

I tried adding this code to my pom.xml

```xml
<reporting>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <outputDirectory>D:/eclipse_ws/reports</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <outputDirectory>D:/eclipse_ws/reports</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

and executing this in windows command prompt

`mvn surefire-report:report -DoutputDirectory=D:/eclipse_ws/reports`

I am still getting the surefire-report.html report in the target/site/ folder itself.
Is it possible to change the directory in the way I did? Did I make any mistake?

Comment: and also, I am really really sorry to say, once i made it to save in desired directory, as D:/eclipse_ws/reports/surefire-report.html
I cannot recollect at all how I did it.. Please help.

Comment: It's odd that you have specified outputDirectory in the pom and on the command line. Have you tried running just mvn surefire-report:report

Comment: yes I guess my configuration in the pom file doesnt work. :( givin it and not givin doesnot make any difference.. Actually I look for a console command itself. :(

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? Maven 3 use maven-site-plugin 3.X furthermore making configuration with absolution paths is completely the wrong way. Leave the defaults and let maven do it's job.

Comment: 3.0.4.. actually i did it before.. :( bad me, forgot to document

Comment: the thing is that i need all the projects' reports in a single folder..

Answer (score 1):

The configuring the output location for surefire report from [report plugin doc](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/report-custom-location.html) seems to be indeed wrong.

I found on [this doc page](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/report-mojo.html) 
description of `<xrefLocation>` parameter of `surefire-report:report` goal, which refers to `${project.reporting.outputDirectory}` value. I tried in my pom.xml and it worked:

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/new-reports-dir</outputDirectory>
</reporting>
```

Comment: The `reporting/outputDirectory` is the correct place to put. I tested with Java 11 and `maven-site-plugin:3.8.2`

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation suggests that the configuration similar to OP's [should work](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/report-custom-location.html), but it doesn't.

What worked for me is:

```
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>C:/eclipse_ws/reports</reportsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

A relative path works as well. Also you don't need to specify the directory as a command line parameter because you already did it in the configuration.